# How do I pick a random unassigned port on localhost

Tags: windows, networking

I am building an application and want to pick a random unassigned port above 1024 to host that application.  How can I do that?

Comment: Use a random number generator, try to bind the socket, if successful then its unused.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Above 1024" you are indirectly referencing to know what ports can be used by server for listening.

Approx way :
if yes `netstat -pant | grep "portno"`  if there is no output there is no server listening to this port and can be used.

If you try to bind to a used port you will get notable to bind error.

Comment: This is what I'm doing, but with Powershell, `netstat -an | sls ":8080"`